# Proof of a sum of positive divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer greater than zero. Prove

$$(\sum_{d|n}v(d)){}^{2}=\sum_{d|n}(v(d))^{3}$$

where $v(d)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$.

I'll outline what my problem is. I write $n= p_{1}^{a_{1}}, p_{2}^{a_{2}}, \cdots , p_{m}^{a_{m}}$. Then I write out each divisor $d_{1}, d_{2}, ..., d_{(a_{1} + 1)(a_{2}+1)...(a_{m} + 1)}$ for $n$. Then

$$(\sum_{d|n}v(d)){}^{2}=(v(d_{1})+v(d_{2})+\ldots+v(d_{(a_{1}+1)(a_{2}+1)\cdots(a_{m}+1)}))^{2},
 $$

but now how do I simplify anything? I don't know how many divisors of EACH $d_{i}$ there are. $d_{i}$ might be prime, it might have 3 divisors--I don't know. That depends on the prime factorization of $d_{i}$. So now I have to write each $d_{i}$ in its very own prime factorization, so I'll have $(a_{1}+1)(a_{2}+1)\cdots(a_{m}+1)$ prime factorizations written out. That's just silly. I realize $v(d)$ is multiplicative but so what? I still have to actually know how many divisors each divisor will have, which means I have to write out each divisor in its own prime factorization.

Comment: Isn't it the case that both sides are multiplicative functions? so all you have to do is prove it in the case where $n$ is a prime power?

Comment: THe book says that as a hint but it also said "why?". Honestly I missed a couple of classes and I don't see how multiplicativity implies that we don't have to show it for any integer; but rather, any prime power. I guess I'll just do it but I don't know why I'm doing it!

Comment: When a function is multiplicative, it is completely determined by its values on prime powers.

Comment: The book keeps saying that and I'm trying to apply it and figure out what it means. I guess it's because if $ab$ is not a prime power, then we could write $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ and consider each $f(a)$ individually, right?

Comment: You can factor any integer into powers of different primes, and then evaluate $f$ as the product of its values on the prime powers.

Comment: Yes, and then we consider the individual case for $f$ applied to a single one of those prime powers. That's what i was saying. Now I get it. Thank you so much for mentioning this. This is what I get for missing class...2 hours of sleep and endless frustration.

Comment: If you get it, write it up, and post it as an answer, please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I cannot help but wonder whether there might be some connection with the following [Faulhaber formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber_formula#Examples): $\big(\sum n\big)^2=\sum n^3$

Comment: @Lucian: It follows directly from the above identity and multiplicativity.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly show $v$ is multiplicative:

Let $a, b$ be relatively prime integers, so $a=p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{m}^{a_{m}}$ and $b=p_{1'}^{b_{1}}p_{2'}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{n}^{a_{n}}
 $. They have no primes in common as we assume they are relatively prime.

Then $$v(ab) = v((p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{m}^{a_{m}})(p_{1'}^{b_{1}}p_{2'}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{n}^{a_{n}}))$$
$$=  v(p_{1}^{a_{1}}p_{2}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{m}^{a_{m}}p_{1'}^{b_{1}}p_{2'}^{a_{2}}\cdots p_{n}^{a_{n}})$$

and by a properties previously established in my textbook

$$=(a_{1}+1)(a_{2}+1)\cdots(a_{m}+1)(b_{1}+1)(b_{2}+2)\cdots(b_{n}+1)$$
$$=\left((a_{1}+1)(a_{2}+1)\cdots(a_{m}+1)\right)\left((b_{1}+1)(b_{2}+2)\cdots(b_{n}+1)\right)$$
$$v(a)v(b).$$

I realize this leaves out a lot but for purposes of my question and given the information in the book that has already been established, it would suffice for my assignment (I believe).

So now this means $v(d)$ is completely determined by its values on prime powers, and so we can assume $n$ is a prime power. Let $n = p^{a}$ for some positive integer $a$. Then all the divisors of $n$ are $\left\{ 1,p,p^{2},p^{3},\ldots,p^{a}\right\}.$

$$(\sum_{d|n}v(d)){}^{2}=(\sum_{d|p^{a}}v(d)){}^{2}$$
$$= v(1) + v(p) + v(p^{2}) + ... + v(p^{a})$$
$$=(1+(1+1)+(2+1)+...+(a+1))^{2}$$
$$=(1+2+3+...+a+1)^{2}$$
$$=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{a}k+1\right)^{2}$$
and by [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber_formula#Examples), we have
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{a}\left(k+1\right)^{3}$$
$$=1^{3}+ 2^{3} + 3^{3} + ... + (a+1)^{3}$$
$$=1 + (1+1)^{3} + (2+1)^{3} + ... (a+1)^{3}$$
So by definition of $v$,
$$=v(1) + v(p^{1})^{3} + v(p^{2})^{3} + ... + v(p^{a})^{3}$$
$$=\sum_{d|p^{a}}\left(v(d)\right)^{3}$$
and since $n=p^{a}$,
$$\sum_{d|n}\left(v(d)\right)^{3}\blacksquare
 $$

Comment: That's the idea, but it's not enough to show that $v(d)$ is multiplicative, you need to show that $(\sum_{d\mid n}v(d))^2$ is multiplicative and that $\sum_{d\mid n}(v(d))^3$ is multiplicative. To do that, you have to show that if $f$ is multiplicative then so is $f^m$ for all $m$, and you probably have a theorem that says that if $f$ is multiplicative then so is $\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm around, just really busy with some graph theory at the moment.